# How to make a bash script portable on OSX

Tags: macos, bash

First time asking a question here. 
New to programing so please be nice if my terminology is a bit off.

I am working in OSX

I have a bash script that has a function in it called pythonb that executes a python file.

I am trying to make this portable, but I can not get this to work unless I put the full path of the python script in the function call.

I thought that since the main bash.sh was in the same directory as the python file I would not need to state the directory of the python script.
I have tried using python ./foo.py  and python foo.py in the function but I still get a python: can't open file 'foo.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.  How do I made this portable? Thank you all in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash
function dothis {
    filename=$(date +"%m-%d-%y|||%H%M%S")
    dothis -x $filename.png
    curl -T $filename.png -u beast:password ftp
}
function sayit {
    say " I wish I knew more about all this"
}

function pythonb {
   python /volumes/FUN/sexy/morefun/foo.py
}

dothis
sayit
pythonb
exit
```

Comment: You have infinite recursion in the `dothis` function.

Comment: If you are new to bash and programming, it may be worth pointing out that you can add "-xv" at the end of the first line to assist in debugging your script, like this..   #!/bin/bash -xv

Comment: You could also add a line like "pwd" and/or "ls" just before the "python" line to see if you are where you think you are and the files you expect to be present are present.

Comment: This is actually very hard to do in general -- see [BashFAQ #28](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) for options and explanations of what can go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hardcoding the full path, you can learn it from $0 -- that's the name of the current script:

```
python "$(dirname "$0")/foo.py"
```

Yes, you should use all those quotes